# Swift for in loop with var instead of let element?

Tags: swift

**Is there some kind of for in loop like the following?**

```
for var score in scores {
...
}
```

I want that score is variable. How can I do that?

Edit: I want that score is a var instead of a let. So that I can do:

```
score = nil
```

Comment: Why do you wanna do that ? You cannot use the variable outside the for loop block!

Comment: Suppose you want to use the variable *inside* the for loop block.

Comment: Completely legit question.

Comment: Is it sane, if legal, to modify the iteration variable within the scope of the loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign a variable `nil` the array must be defined with an optional type. Perhaps you can use the Array higher order sequence map to construct a new array?

```
var scores: [Int?] = [1, 2, 3, 4, nil, 5, 6, 7, 8]
scores = scores.map { (score: Int?) -> Int? in
    return nil
}
```